# Sorting out similar values in the same column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to categorize data that seem to similar from my database table.

Here's how the table looks like

| id | account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 011 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 023 |
| 4 | 23 |
| 5 | 456 |

I need a select query that will categorize my data as in the table below ignoring the unique values.

I can achieve this in pandas but I would appreciate if I also learn how to achieve the same in SQL

| id | account1 | account2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 011 | 11 |
| 2 | 023 | 23 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the simple answer is properly store `account` as data type numeric or integer, then just check for duplicates, remove them, and finally put a unique constraint on `account` - done problem solved. But assuming I will hear *I can not change the database* becomes a different story. The first thing you need is filter out any non-numeric account values (may just be me but I never trust text columns to actually contain numeric data). Then with that out-of-the-way do a self on the remaining and assign the new id. The result becomes: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=488732d0ac9569713006c11d0a1035ab))

```
with num_acct (id, account) as 
     (select *
        from test 
       where account ~ '^[0-9]+$'
     )     
select row_number() over() as id  
     , na1.account as account1 
     , na2.account as account2 
  from num_acct na1
  join num_acct na2
    on (    na1.account::integer = na2.account::integer 
        and na1.id < na2.id
       );
```

Comment: help me understand why you used row_number() over() in the select statement

Comment: See [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html). The row_number() function counts the rows within each specified PARTITION (the Window Version of Group by) within the OVER clause.  Omitting anything to partition indicates to Postgres to build a single partition; thus counting the rows returned.  Tho only reason was to get ids for requested results, Using the id from the would have produced 1 and 3. Note: there is no ordering here, just count or the output rows

Answer (score 1):

```sql
with data as (
  select
    id,
    account as account1,
    last_value(account) over (partition by account::numeric) as account2
  from your_table
)
select id, account1, account2 from data where account1 != account2;
```

Comment: i tried executing your query but for some reasons I have failed to figure out, it returns 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

It is not an obvious

- data type;
- what mean account2 field the result table;
- which data must place in id field the result table;

Below is the quick and duty solution.

In subquery count unique data by [count(*)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-aggregate.html) agregate function.

```sql
SELECT id, account::INTEGER
FROM
(select *, count(account::INTEGER) over (partition by account::INTEGER) as count from
(VALUES
(1, '011'),
(2, '11'),
(3, '023'),
(4, '23'),
(5, '456')
) as "ID"(id, account)) as "ID"(id, account)
where count > 1
```